# Post form data using Fetch in Redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, redux-saga

```
var formData = new FormData(loginRequestObject);
formData.append('userName', loginRequestObject.username);
formData.append('password', loginRequestObject.password);
formData.append('mobile', loginRequestObject.mobile);
formData.append('deviceid', deviceInfo.getDeviceId())
```

This is the request What I am making-

and in body part

```
  try{
const response = yield call(fetch, Url, {
  method : 'POST',
  headers : {
    'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
    'Content-Type' :'multipart/form-data, application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
  },
  body : formData
}) 
if(response.ok) {
  const jsonResponse = yield response.text()
  yield put(LoginActions.loginSuccess(jsonResponse))
} else {
  const jsonResponse = yield response.text();
  yield put(LoginActions.loginFailure(jsonResponse))
}
```

I am making this request to post the data but I'm not able to do , what is the reason?

Comment: you code looks ok, how did you see that it doesn't work ? does it send an http post ?

Comment: What is this call function about ? Why aren't you just using the ES6 fetch to post your fromData to your server? Have you checked in your network tab if something happend?

Comment: When I am using posting it is telling ** type == null **. and at the time when I am using ` body:JSON.stringify(formData) ` than network call is happening but the values are going to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no `promise function` handling the response of your `POST` request. What error are you getting with this implemented code? Why are you using `multipart/form-data` when you are not sending data in multiple parts? From your code it doesn't look like you are sending the image data for which you need `multipart`.

Your question doesn't provide enough details to provide any specific answer, please explain it with more details about the error you are getting.

Comment: added **multipart/form-data** because I am getting diffrent diffrent Array, and If I am removing that I am getting error as multipart !=application/x-www-form-url-enoded'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap fetch function with another function, this is a demo for you

```
const fetchFunc = ({ url, options }) => {
   return fetch(url, options);
}

const response = yield call(fetchFunc, {
     url: Url,
     options {
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
          'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
          'Content-Type' :'multipart/form-data, application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
        },
        body : formData
    }
}); 
if(response.ok) {
   const jsonResponse = yield response.text()
   yield put(LoginActions.loginSuccess(jsonResponse))
} else {
   const jsonResponse = yield response.text();
   yield put(LoginActions.loginFailure(jsonResponse))
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just I have removed the Content-Type and it has worked.